# python mailchimp api 2.0 json response error

Tags: python, mysql, json, mailchimp

Hi I'm trying to set up a batch job taking data from the mysql database and send those users to mailchimp to be used for direct email campaigns. I'm having an issue with the my code running on python 2.6 Red Hat linux (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) and python 2.7.3 Debian 4.6.3-14. I know this code works on windows 7 python 2.7.2 anaconda ipython notebook but I get a mailchimp json response error at the end I don't fully understand.

```
import mysql.connector
import mailchimp



#prepare mysql connection
def connection(query):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='x', password='x',
                              host='x',
                              port=xxxx,
                              connection_timeout=60,
                              database='database')

    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    data=cursor.fetchall ()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    return data


#execute query

email_data=None
query_con = ("SELECT * FROM email")
email_data=connection(query_con)


#set mailchimp api key
apikey='key'


#create mailchimp oauth instance
m=mailchimp.Mailchimp(apikey)

#set list id to target mailchimp list
list_id='xxxx'

#method to format table data to mailchimp structure
def batch_load(data):
    b_load= [{"email":{"email":x[3]},"merge_vars":{"FNAME":x[1],"LNAME":x[2], "MMERGE3":x[0], 
                                               "MMERGE4":x[6], "MMERGE5":x[7], "MMERGE6":x[8], "MMERGE7":x[10], "MMERGE8":x[11], 
                                               "MMERGE9":x[12], "MMERGE10":x[13],"MMERGE11":x[14], "MMERGE12":x[16],
                                               "MMERGE13":x[17]}} for x in data]
    return b_load


#use method
b_load=batch_load(email_data)
#upload users to mailchimp with parameters: list_id, formated_data, no double op in, allow updates, do not update interests. 
m.lists.batch_subscribe(list_id,b_load,False,True,False)
```

Here's a json upload sample:

```
{
'merge_vars': {
    'LNAME': u'Client',
    'MMERGE8': datetime.datetime(2014,
    6,
    20,
    7,
    33,
    43),
    'MMERGE9': 0,
    'FNAME': u'Dev',
    'MMERGE3': 74,
    'MMERGE6': 2,
    'MMERGE7': 99,
    'MMERGE4': u'(111)111-1111',
    'MMERGE5': u'90210',
    'MMERGE10': datetime.datetime(2015,
    3,
    9,
    14,
    4,
    50),
    'MMERGE11': None,
    'MMERGE12': None,
    'MMERGE13': 0
},
'email': {
    'email': u'dev@dev.com'
}
```

}

Here's the error it seems like there's an issue with the date time format:

```
File "/foo/bar/batch_job.py", line 113, in <module>
    m.lists.batch_subscribe(list_id,b_load,False,True,False)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mailchimp.py", line 1393, in batch_subscribe
    return self.master.call('lists/batch-subscribe', _params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mailchimp.py", line 351, in call
    params = json.dumps(params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 370, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 269, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 348, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 246, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 20, 7, 33, 43) is not JSON serializable
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a Python error, not a MailChimp error. the JSON module doesn't know how to turn a datetime object into a JSON Value. You'll need to convert it into a string yourself. MailChimp should be able to accept the isoformat() string or, if you're working with a Date Merge Field (where time isn't needed) you can call date().isoformat(). Here's some code that gets converted into JSON properly:

```
json.dumps({
    'merge_vars': {
        'LNAME': u'Client',
        'MMERGE8': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 20, 7, 33, 43).date().isoformat(),
        'MMERGE9': 0,
        'FNAME': u'Dev',
        'MMERGE3': 74,
        'MMERGE6': 2,
        'MMERGE7': 99,
        'MMERGE4': u'(111)111-1111',
        'MMERGE5': u'90210',
        'MMERGE10': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 9, 14, 4, 50).date().isoformat(),
        'MMERGE11': None,
        'MMERGE12': None,
        'MMERGE13': 0
    },
    'email': {
        'email': u'dev@dev.com'
    }
})
```

You'll notice if you remove the `.date().isoformat()` from either `MMERGE8` or `MMERGE10` that your error comes back.

Comment: Yup it was a json time format error. Fixed afterwards. Thanks!